# How to create an event using batch file?

Tags: batch-file

Iam having a code to export text files to excel sheet.How to create a batch file for that so that the batch file wil trigger that event(exporting) once the text file is received

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop and detect the filetype: This will check for the filetype every 5 seconds.

```
:loop
if not exist *.txt timeout /t 5 /nobreak & goto :loop
:: launch your code here
goto :loop
```